# Searching thousands of records with SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with thousands of records, I'm using the below query to get result in 30 sec but it's working very slow. How can I do better?

```
 WITH cte AS 
 (select 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sb.nbofviews desc) AS ROW,   
     sb.ImageId, sb.LicenceType, sb.ImgCollection, sb.nbofviews, 
     sb.orientation, sb.shootdate, sd.ImgName, sd.Caption, sd.ImgPath, 
     sd.ImageType, sd.ImgHoverPath, sc.image_color 
  from 
     SearchBrain sb,SearchDetails sd, searchcolors sc 
  where 
     sc.Imageid = sd.Imageid 
     and sb.ImageId = sd.ImageId 
     and sd.imageid in (select ImageId 
                        from SearchInitial 
                        where Primarykeyword = 
                             (Select top 1 Primary_kwd 
                              from p2_kwdmgmt 
                              where all_kwd = 'man') 
                        intersect 
                        select ImageId 
                        from SearchInitial 
                        where Primarykeyword = 
                              (Select top 1 Primary_kwd 
                               from p2_kwdmgmt 
                               where all_kwd = 'jumping') 
                        intersect 
                        select ImageId 
                        from SearchInitial 
                        where Primarykeyword = 
                              (Select top 1 Primary_kwd 
                               from p2_kwdmgmt 
                               where all_kwd = 'beach')
                       )
) 
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE ROW BETWEEN 0 AND 31
```

Comment: Please edit the question to make it readable.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following. Just check the part with `In ('man','jumping','beach') GROUP BY Primary_kwd` if it produces the correct result.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sb.nbofviews DESC) AS ROW
  ,sb.ImageId
  ,sb.LicenceType
  ,sb.ImgCollection
  ,sb.nbofviews
  ,sb.orientation
  ,sb.shootdate
  ,sd.ImgName
  ,sd.Caption
  ,sd.ImgPath
  ,sd.ImageType
  ,sd.ImgHoverPath
  , sc.image_color 
FROM SearchBrain sb,SearchDetails sd, searchcolors sc 
WHERE sc.Imageid=sd.Imageid AND sb.ImageId=sd.ImageId AND sd.imageid in 
(
    SELECT ImageId FROM SearchInitial WHERE Primarykeyword In (SELECT Primary_kwd FROM p2_kwdmgmt WHERE all_kwd In ('man','jumping','beach') GROUP BY Primary_kwd) 
)
) 
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE ROW BETWEEN 0 AND 31
```

Comment: it's showing seperate result but i'm trying to find only man jumping on beach.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Hope this helps.

```
 WITH cte AS 
 (select 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sb.nbofviews desc) AS ROW,   
     sb.ImageId, sb.LicenceType, sb.ImgCollection, sb.nbofviews, 
     sb.orientation, sb.shootdate, sd.ImgName, sd.Caption, sd.ImgPath, 
     sd.ImageType, sd.ImgHoverPath, sc.image_color 
  from (SELECT * FROM SearchDetails 
        WHERE imageid in (select ImageId 
                        from SearchInitial 
                        where Primarykeyword = 
                             (Select top 1 Primary_kwd 
                              from p2_kwdmgmt 
                              where all_kwd = 'man'))
              OR imageid in (select ImageId 
                        from SearchInitial 
                        where Primarykeyword = 
                             (Select top 1 Primary_kwd 
                              from p2_kwdmgmt 
                              where all_kwd = 'jumping'))
              OR imageid in (select ImageId 
                        from SearchInitial 
                        where Primarykeyword = 
                             (Select top 1 Primary_kwd 
                              from p2_kwdmgmt 
                              where all_kwd = 'beach'))
        ) sd
     INNER JOIN SearchBrain sb ON sd.ImageId = sb.ImageId
     INNER JOIN searchcolors sc ON sd.ImageId = sc.ImageId 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE ROW BETWEEN 0 AND 31
```

Comment: :- it's showing seperate result. plz check my table structure. `Uid Primarykeyword Imageid Priority
1 Man  1061882 0
2 Jumping  1061882 0
3 Beach  1061882 0
4 Man  1061883 0
5 Jumping  1061883 0
6 Beach  1061883 0`